# Qt access mainWindow in a class without giving the object to it

Tags: c++, qt, class, oop, object

I need to access the mainWindow object in a different class. The problem is, that I can not give mainWindow to this class (I don't want to do this, it would make everything much more complicated). Question: Is there any way in C++ or Qt to put an object in something like a local "database" or sth where every other class in the project can look into and communicate with the objects.
What I want to have in the end is something like this:

```
// A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class A{
public:
    A() { /*here comes the ting*/ myMainWindow->sayHi(); }
};
#endif // A_H


// MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "a.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    A *a = new A;
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow(){delete ui;}
MainWindow::sayHi(){
    // just do anything
}
```

I don't think, this is possible, but I give it a try...
Thanks for answers!

Comment: Why you need mainWindow object?  you can access main from other classes  with signals and slots. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: But I need to call it on the mainWindow object itself. I my mainWindow class, I implemented a function and I want to execute this function when I do something what only other class receives, but not the mainWindow. For connecting this class with the right mainWindow slot, I need the actual mainWindow object

Comment: Put signal-slot connections in your main. it's possible. i don't know anything about your project but it is possible

Comment: @mep What do you mean exactly with access, do you mean to use one of their methods?

Comment: Yes, that is exactely what I want. I cant connect it in the main, because the class, from which I try to call this methon in mainWindow is created in another class, that also does not know mainWindow

Comment: @mep You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there are multiple answers but it depends on how you have implemented your classes. In addition to the code you must show, I ask you to share your project through github, gist or similar.

Comment: Yes, I already did, just reload :) Well I gave an example, that is showing the problem good I think. The actual project is too big, the object hirarchy is a bit complicated, but I think, the code sample should work

Comment: @mep Place a code that can be executed: Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example, You want your code to be reproducible, missing many details, Class A and B inherit from some class? How is your question currently broad and off-topic in SO.

Comment: No, A and B do not inherit from any class, otherwise I would have written it down

Comment: When you show an MVCE then I can just help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to access the mainWindow object in a different class. The
>   problem is, that I can not give mainWindow to this class (I don't want
>   to do this, it would make everything much more complicated).

That is doable. The author don't want to expose the "main window" variable holding the reference or pointer to the object. And, obviously the author wants that UI object to be callable from other objects. In Qt that implies either both objects on UI thread or communication is via queued signal-slot connection only. But the direct call wanted, hence on the same thread.

> Is there any way in C++ or Qt to put an object in something like a
>   local "database" or sth where every other class in the project can
>   look into and communicate with the objects.

Local thread storage is a known pattern to implement things like that. Qt has own implementation of it called [QThreadStorage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadstorage.html). You can attempt something like that:

```
// myLts.h
void ltsRegisterObject(const QString &key, QObject *object);
void ltsRemoveObject(const QString &key);
QObject* ltsGetObject(const QString &key);
template <typename T> T* ltsGet(const QString &key) {
     return qobject_cast<T*>(ltsGetObject(key));
}


// myLts.cpp
static QThreadStorage<QMap<QString, QObject*> > s_qtObjects;

void ltsRegisterObject(const QString &key, QObject *object)
{
    s_qtObjects.localData().insert(key, object);
}

void ltsRemoveObject(const QString &key)
{
    if (!s_qtObjects.hasLocalData())
        return;

    s_qtObjects.localData().remove(key);
}

QObject* ltsGetObject(const QString &key)
{
    QObject *object;
    auto it = s_qtObjects.localData().find(key);
    return it != s_qtObjects.localData().end() ? it.value() : nullptr;
}
```

Register main window object in LTS:

```
#include "myLts.h"
// ...
// register main window in LTS
ltsRegisterObject("mainWindow", &mainWindow);
```

Find and use the object:

```
#include "myLts.h"
// ...
// use main window from LTS
auto* pMainWnd = ltsGet<QMainWindow>("mainWindow");
if (pMainWnd)
    pMainWnd->show();
```

P.S. I did not compile this. But it is not hard to fix if so.

Comment: Oh, beautiful, thanks! That looks like a perfect solution if it works. I will try...

Comment: Made 2 fixes for obvious typos.

Comment: I get four errors in framework files... I guess this is the "main" one: \include\QtCore\qobjectdefs.h:544: error: creating pointer to member function of non-class type 'QMainWindow*'
         _static int test(int (Object::*)(QMetaObject::Call, int, void **));_  honestly, I have no idea...

Comment: Then there is no QMailWindow included at that file. `#include <QMainWindow>`. Are you a student?

Comment: Were you ever able to compile that project before changes?

Comment: Yes. At the beginning and even after. I unfortunately don't know, when it came the first time

Comment: BTW, I fixed precisely `ltsGet<QMainWindow>("mainWindow");`. No more pointer after QMainWindow here. You need to include all the Qt types you refer to. Look at Qt docs/examples for the type to make it includable.  Also, there `QT + = something` statements in project file to include the whole Qt module if needed. But I doubt the latter as long as you were able to compile widgets. Other that that it seems you need a bit more exercises in the area. The advise is good when the person is ready to apply it.

Comment: Well, I remade it and now it works.... still searching the mistake. But good news, it works. Well getting experience is exactely what I do with that kind of stuff, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, well thats it :)) Adding the pointer ( _ltsGet<QMainWindow*>_ ) and the errors are saying hi again.